# Which package can be used for a square icon of @ while creating a resume? I can't find it in the package fontawesome

Tags: cv, icon, deedy-resume

I was creating my resume with a latex template and was inserting contact icons in it.
I needed the icons for phone, email, linkedin and github. I found square icons for linkedin, github and phone. But @ has only the simple logo, without an outside square.

I was curious why @ doesn't have an outside black square and how I can add it in my resume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual symbol for email is an envelope (or similar). I expect that's why you can't find an icon consisting of the @ symbol inside a square. You can use the [fontawesome package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) to produce all the symbols you need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\faLinkedinSquare\quad
\faPhoneSquare\quad
\faGitSquare\quad
\faEnvelopeSquare
\end{document}
```

[image: symbols]